# How can i fetch key value from Error in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, nserror

How can i fetch message value from this error result in the best way. I trie a lot but never got the value, so please help me

```
 BUYClient.sharedClient.createCustomer(with: credentials) { (customer : BUYCustomer?,token:  BUYCustomerToken?, error :Error?) -> Void in
                if customer != nil{
                    print(token ?? "kuch nahi aaya")
                    print(customer?.fullName ?? "kuch nahi aaya")
                }
                let customer = error.debugDescription

                print("value===\(customer)")
            }
```

Result :

```
     value===Optional(Error Domain=BUYShopifyErrorDomain Code=422 "(null)" UserInfo={errors={
            customer =     {
                email =         (
                                {
                        code = taken;
                        message = "has already been taken";
                        options =                 {
                            "rescue_from_duplicate" = 1;
                            value = "y@gmail.com";
                        };
                    }
                );
            };
        }})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access the userInfo of the error you have to cast your `Error` to a classic `NSError`, after that you can access the `userInfo` like a dictionary.

```
let nserror = error as! NSError
if let errors = nserror.userInfo["errors"] as? [String: NSObject],
   let customer = errors["customer"] as? [String: NSObject],
   let email = customer["email"] as? [[String: NSObject]]
{
    let message = email[0]["message"]
}
```

Comment: thanks for answered me but its not working it gives error getter/setter not initailized

Comment: I was missing an `if` in my code. If the error is still there please update your question with the new code you have tried, so I can see how you trying to use it. And Please post the full compiler/runtime error and the line in which it is occurring.

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSError' i got this error at this line if let nserror = error as NSError ,

Comment: That's what I meant by that maybe some `?` and `!`are missing. I edited my answer.

Comment: Type 'Any?' has no subscript members now i got this error at this line  let message = nserror.userInfo["errors"]["customer"]["email"][0]["message"] thank for consideration me

Comment: Edited again. If it still not works maybe there is some optional chaining `?` for the `[0]`.

Comment: Edited it again. I rebuild your error object in a playground and found the same error as you. Now I added a working solution.

Comment: thanks for answering me you are great. and please add this line let nserror = error as! NSError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136860/discussion-between-yatish-agrawal-and-kie).